# Disable Screen Sleep AppleScript

Tags: applescript, screen, screen-lock

Is there a way to turn screen sleeping on and off temporarily through AppleScript? I'm making a script at the moment that will run for a few minutes when I'm away, so I don't want it to sleep, but don't want to manually do it every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly the easiest way to accomplish this is by using `do shell script`. `pmset` is definitely a viable option, though I am personally partial to the [`caffeinate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/caffeinate.8.html) command, which doesn't modify any preferences and doesn't require administrator privileges. You could use the following AppleScript to keep your screen awake indefinitely:

```
do shell script "caffeinate -di"
```

Alternatively, you can run caffeinate for a specified amount of time, after which your display will be free to go to sleep:

```
do shell script "caffeinate -dit [time in seconds]"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the AppleScript [**do shell script**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2065/_index.html) command with the [`pmset`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pmset.1.html) command to alter the energy saving settings.

The following example disables display sleep:

```
do shell script "pmset -a displaysleep 0" with administrator privileges
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do `caffeinate -i <SHELL_SCRIPT>`.

From the caffeinate manpage:

```bash
     caffeinate -i make
        caffeinate forks a process, execs "make" in it, and holds an assertion that prevents idle sleep as long as that
     process is running.
```